# Template MySQL zabbix

Tags: mysql, monitoring, zabbix

I am trying to monitor a database using this template https://share.zabbix.com/databases/mysql/template-mysql-800-items, the instructions do not indicate where I should place each file and modify each configuration, does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a large scale question, but in general, the XML file is imported in the Zabbix frontend, while the Perl script goes in /opt/mysql_check.pl (or wherever you point at in the userparameter entry in the agent daemon configuration file).